# Pod cassandra-0 root password after deploying from bitnami helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, kubernetes-helm, vmware, bitnami

I have deployed a cassandra and I want to edit a file cassandra-env.sh which is inside of the pod for making changes on JVM settings. But I cannot edit the file nor I can install any package, hence it needs sudo permission, How do I install or how to reset the sudo password.

(helical-math-347004)$ kubectl get pods

NAME               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

cassandra-0        2/2     Running   0          4h55m
cassandra-client   1/1     Running   0          67m
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sudo will allow your system administrators to grant certain users (or groups of users) the ability to run commands as root. What’s important is that all commands and arguments will be logged as part of your security and compliance protocol. Make sure that you configure your sudo security policy to log activity. You can do this using the file /etc/sudoers. Within the sudoers file, configure your groups of users and sets of commands to simplify, and audit server administration with sudo commands.

Steps to create a new sudo user

**1) **Log in to your Ubuntu server as the root user**.**

```
ssh root@server_ip_address
```

**2) Use the “adduser” command to add a new user to your system.**

**3) Use the “usermod” command to add the user to the sudo group.**

```
usermod -aG sudo derek
```

By default, on Ubuntu, members of the sudo group have sudo privileges.

**4) Test sudo access on the new user account**

- Use the su command to switch to the new user account.

  su – username
- As the new user, verify that you can use sudo by adding "sudo" to the
  beginning of the command that you want to run with superuser
  privilages.

  sudo command_to_run
- The first time you use sudo in a session, the system will prompt you
  for     the password of the user account. Enter the password to
  proceed.

For more detailed steps refer to  the [link](https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/entry/unix-linux-privileged-management-should-you-sudo).